# How to change color ramp in graduated classification with standard deviation using pyqgis

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, symbology

I'm using **graduated** clasiffication with **standard deviation** to style my shapefile (see code below). But I need to use different color ramp for classes below mean (-1std, -2std etc.).I'm thinking of looping over classes below mean and change the color to blue. But how can I choose the appropriate color from blue ramp.

```
from qgis.core import  (QgsVectorLayer, QgsMapLayerRegistry, QgsGraduatedSymbolRendererV2, QgsSymbolV2,QgsRendererRangeV2)
from PyQt4 import QtGui

def validatedDefaultSymbol( geometryType ):
    symbol = QgsSymbolV2.defaultSymbol( geometryType )
    if symbol is None:
        if geometryType == QGis.Point:
            symbol = QgsMarkerSymbolV2()
        elif geometryType == QGis.Line:
            symbol =  QgsLineSymbolV2 ()
        elif geometryType == QGis.Polygon:
            symbol = QgsFillSymbolV2 ()
    return symbol


def applyGraduatedSymbologyStandardMode( layer, field, classes, mode):
    symbol = validatedDefaultSymbol( layer.geometryType() )
    colorRamp = QgsVectorGradientColorRampV2.create({'color1':'255,0,0,255', 'color2':'0,0,255,255','stops':'0.25;255,255,0,255:0.50;0,255,0,255:0.75;0,255,255,255'})
    renderer = QgsGraduatedSymbolRendererV2.createRenderer( layer, targetField, classes, mode, symbol, colorRamp )
    layer.setRendererV2( renderer )


targetField = 'myfield'

classes = 6

layer = QgsVectorLayer('myshapefile.shp', "My Layer" , 'ogr')

if layer.isValid():
    applyGraduatedSymbologyStandardMode( layer, targetField, classes, QgsGraduatedSymbolRendererV2.StdDev)
    QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayers( [layer] )
```